# Capture Silence on Google Home

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, api-ai

Can we get Google send something when the person stays silent in a conversation? A "no.response" intent before closing the microphone. I'm thinking of an "are you still there" question scenario or timed question/response games.

The point is not to close the session and give a chance to continue.

This would happen only once (or configurable times) so the microphone would not stay open. ﻿

Answer (score 1):

When using the client library assistant.ask method, remember to specify values for the no-inputs parameters. You can use that to prompt the user to respond when the microphone doesn't hear anything.

Comment: I understand. I'm doing that. But I want to let the fulfillment server know that there was no answer. Like in a timed trivia game.

Comment: By the way one of the no-input prompts gets lost. I only hear the first two. Is that a bug or I'm doing something wrong. I'm sending ['First prompt', 'Second prompt', 'Good Bye!"].

Comment: Yes, that is a known bug. Working on a fix.